# Finding the starting x coordinate of text in a right-aligned PdfPCell

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to accomplish a formatted table in iTextSharp.

The table would be two columns, the left being left-aligned and right being right-aligned with a dotted line between the values in the right and left columns.

Since I do not wish to use a fixed-width/monospace font, my attempts so far have been to try to identify the end of the text in the left column and the start of the text in the right column to draw a dotted line between those two points, however I'm struggling to get those coordinate values.

```
string item = "Case #: ";
string value = record.CaseID;

// Initialize left cell of row
PdfPCell itemCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item, regular));
itemCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; // Left
caseSummaryTable.AddCell(itemCell);

// Resolve left cell in row to get end point
columnText.Go();
float xItemEnd = columnText.LastX;
float yItemEnd = columnText.YLine;

// Initialize right cell of row
PdfPCell valueCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, regular));
valueCell.HorizontalAlignment = 2; // Right
caseSummaryTable.AddCell(valueCell);

// Resolve right cell in row
// Attempt to get usable start X coordinate
columnText.Go();
float xValueStart = columnText.LastX; // ?
float yValueStart = columnText.YLine; // ?
```

The LastX get method returns 0 in both uses, whereas the YLine appears to be returning a usable value. Has anyone tips to determine the coordinates that I need?

Answer (score 0):

```
                    string item = "Case #: ";
                    string value = record.CaseID;

                    // Initialize left cell of row
                    PdfPCell itemCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item, regular));
                    itemCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; // Left
                    itemCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    caseSummaryTable.AddCell(itemCell);

                    // Initialize right cell of row
                    PdfPCell valueCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(value, regular));
                    valueCell.HorizontalAlignment = 2; // Right
                    valueCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    caseSummaryTable.AddCell(valueCell);

                    // Calculate start and end of dotted-line
                    float xItemEnd = x0 + regular.BaseFont.GetWidthPoint(item, fontSize);
                    float xValueStart = x0 + xD - regular.BaseFont.GetWidthPoint(value, fontSize);
                    float rowBaseLine = columnText.YLine - leadingValue;

                    // Draw dotted-line from end of item text to start of value text
                    DottedLineSeparator dottedLine = new DottedLineSeparator();
                    dottedLine.Draw(contentByte, xItemEnd, rowBaseLine, xValueStart, rowBaseLine, rowBaseLine);
```

The trick was getting the calculated width of the strings from that determining the end of the value column text and the start of the value column text.